# Resubmit a csrf protected form after redirect (Symfony1)

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, csrf

To help a user that may leave a form open until the session times out I am trying to resubmit their form after they have been sent through the login page and redirected back to the form. The site has dozens of forms so I'm hoping to make this generic and apply to the parent form so they all get this feature.

Currently if they try to submit a form and no authentication is found (i.e the session timed out or for testing purposes I have logged out via another tab) they are sent to the login page which preserves the post parameters and referrer URL like so:

```
 $this->getUser()->setAttribute('referer', $this->getRequest()->getUri());
 $this->getUser()->setAttribute('postparameters', $this->getRequest()->getPostParameters());
```

Then if they successfully log in they are redirected to the URL

```
 $this->redirect($this->getUser()->getAttribute('referer', '@homepage'));
```

I can't restore the post parameters here since it is a redirect and results in a http GET request. So instead I have put this code into the action where the form is about to be processed

```
$postparams = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('postparameters');
if (is_array($postparams))
{
    foreach($postparams as $key => $postparam)
    {
        $request->setParameter($key, $postparam);
    }
}
```

However the post parameters includes the _csrf_token from the previous session and the form fails validation. If I remove that item from the $postparams array the form is rejected because the token is required. I don't want to disable CSRF protection altogether but I can' find a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have now is to generate a new CSRF token after the form has been found to be invalid and is about to be redrawn

```
public function executeUpdate(sfWebRequest $request)
{

    ...

    if ($this->largePlantForm->isValid())
    {
        ....
    } else {        
        $tempform = new largePlantForm();
        $this->largePlantForm->setValue($tempform->getCSRFFieldName(), $tempform->getCSRFToken());
        $this->setTemplate('edit');
}
```

this relies on a change to BaseForm that adds setValue(). The reason I call this after the form has been declared invalid is that to do so beforehand would mean the csrf_token was always made valid and thus worthless. With my method the user is sent back to the form they were on before being directed to the login page and their values are all there, they need to see the page and submit it along with the fresh csrf_token.